# Custom attribute not present in getProduct()

Tags: product, attributes

I try to retrieve one custom attributes for a product and print in title.phtml.
I have followed all the steps for create a custom attribute and add it to a group correctly and it appears in admin panel and I can insert my custom value.
The problem comes when I try to retrieve the new custom attribute using

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$sample = $_product->getCustomAttribute('sample');
```

If I print the var_dump of **$_product** the custom attribute is missing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure when you add your custom product attribute, you have to add the `visible_on_front` property with value `true`, eg:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    Product::ENTITY,
    'sample',
    [
        ....
        'visible_on_front' => true
    ]
);
```

Assume you custom product atribute code is `sample`, to get your custom product attribute value, use `$product->getData('sample')` or `$product->getSample()`.

If that code does not work in your phtml file, try to use code below:

```
echo $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class)->productAttribute(
    $block->getProduct(),
    $block->getProduct()->getSample(),
    'sample'
)
```

or

```
echo $attributeValue = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('sample')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Comment: Already tried but still, it is not showing cos does not exist when I print the var_dump. @pawan in a similar topic target to use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface

Comment: I don't think you need to use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface, did you try all 3 ways above?

Comment: Yes, I did with not success. btw I always reindex in the end

Comment: Which is the block used for your phtml file?

Comment: \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product

Comment: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View

Comment: So now I figured out. It is something relate to configurable product because I am working on a configurable product

Comment: Glad to hear that.